# How to retrieve form ID in controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have many forms in one page,
my question is how to retrieve the ID of the form sent

Comment: use a submit button name to check which form was sent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

b.b3rn4rd is correct test for the string of the submit (make sure all of your submit buttons say something different).

```
if ($this->getRequest()->getPost('submit') == 'Something Unique') {
// do some stuff
}
```